# Asymptotic expansion of $\operatorname{arsinh}(c/t)$ as $t\rightarrow 0$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, hyperbolic-functions

let $c>0$ be a constant and let $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f(t):=\operatorname{arsinh}(\frac{c}{t})$, where $\operatorname{arsinh}$ denotes the inverse of sinus hyperbolicus. That function has a singularity at $t=0$, and I am interested in an asymptotic expansion in powers of $t$ as $t\rightarrow 0$.

By just guessing and using the rule of l'Hospital, I proved that $f(t)\sim \frac{c}{t}$ as $t\rightarrow 0$. Is it possible to obtain a full asymptotic expansion by a systematic approach?

Best wishes

Comment: You can write this in terms of the logarithm. Then expand in powers of $1/t.$

Comment: Fpr $t \to 0$, your assertion $f(t) \sim \frac{c}{t}$ is wrong.  That is correct for $t \to \infty$.  Which one do you want?

Comment: I want the asymptotic expansion as $t\rightarrow 0$. I am sorry for the confusion. Why is my assertion wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference Gradshtyn & Ryshik

> *Gradshteyn, I. S.; Ryzhik, I. M.; Zwillinger, Daniel (ed.); Moll, Victor (ed.)*, [**Table of integrals, series, and products. Translated from the Russian. Translation edited and with a preface by Victor Moll and Daniel Zwillinger**](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/book/9780123849335), Amsterdam: Elsevier/Academic Press (ISBN 978-0-12-384933-5/hbk; 978-0-12-384934-2/ebook). xlv, 1133 p. (2015). [ZBL1300.65001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1300.65001).

Formula 1.641.2
As $z \to 0$, which corresponds to $t \to \infty$:

\begin{align}
\operatorname{asinh} z &= z - \frac{1}{2\cdot3}\;z^3
 + \frac{1\cdot3}{2\cdot4\cdot5}\;z^5 
-\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot7}\;z^7+\dots
\\ &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty 
\frac{(-1)^k(2k)!z^{2k+1}}{2^{2k}(k!)^2(2k+1)}
= z\;{}_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};-z^2\right)
\end{align}

Formula 1.642.1
As $z \to \infty$, which corresponds to $t \to 0$:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{asinh} z &= \log(2z) + \frac{1}{2}\;\frac{1}{2z^2}
-\frac{1\cdot3}{2\cdot4}\;\frac{1}{4z^4} +\dots
\\ &= \log(2z) + \sum_{k=0}^\infty
\frac{(-1)^{k+1}(2k)!z^{-2k}}{2^{2k}(k!)^2 2k}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful

Answer (score 3):

You have the following expansion of $\operatorname{argsinh}x$, based on the Taylor expansion of its derivative $\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$:
\begin{align}
&\operatorname{argsinh}x=\\
&\phantom{{}={}}x-\frac12\frac{x^3}3+\frac{1\cdot 3}{2\cdot 4}\frac{x^5}5-\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6}\frac{x^7}7 +\dots+(-1)^{2n+1}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}x^{2n+1}+\dotsm 
\end{align}

Comment: But this will give you $\operatorname{asinh}(c/t)$ as $t\to \infty$, not as $t \to 0$.

Comment: @GEdgar: I know no other expansion formula (and I don't think there exists another general formula). The radius of convergence of this series is $1$.  Perhaps doing some hyperbolic trigonometry?

Answer (score 1):

**A little correction**

We use **arg**sinh instead of arcsinh, because we are talking about an argument in an exponential terms $\dfrac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$ and not an arc as in trigonometric function.

Then we have that formula (proved by inversion of $\sinh(y)+\left(1+\sinh^2(y)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=e^y$

$$  \operatorname{argsinh}(x)=\ln(x+\left(1+x^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}) $$

So we have

$$\operatorname{argsinh}(x)=\ln(x) + \ln\left(1+\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)$$

Which gives :

$$\operatorname{argsinh}(x)\sim_\infty \ln(x) $$

For further development use asymptotic development inside the right side term.